# Android How Can I move an ImageView when the user clicks a button (For a game)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have yet to find the solution to this problem. I'm trying to make a game. I want to make an image move to the left, right, up or down when a button is clicked. Please help me as I have struggled with this problem for two days. Please show and explain to me how to move an ImageVıew as explained above.

Thanks in advance.

```
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
bt.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      playerY+=20;`
        player.setY(playerY);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Give us some more information! What's the language? What happens when you run the code? What would you like to see instead?

Comment: .Java Android Studio.I would like to see character moves left but forever.I try to make game

Comment: when I  run this program Character moves down but just once .I would like to see character moves down forever İf I leave to button click My character must to stop Thats what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UpButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Do something
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // No longer down
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Action Down means the button is clicked and action up gets triggered when the finger is no longer on the button

Comment: I didnt try But thank for helping me bro this might be answer

Comment: it didnt work.:(( When to button clicked my character goes down but I would like to see  during the click event my character goes down 
 ı must to say heyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    You will see (y)                             your answer:y       my question:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    Understand? :D

Comment: 1. start a thread in action down
    2. In the thread : write a loop with for whatever you want to do (use a flag to stop the loop)
    3. on ACTION_UP : change the flag to end the loop

Comment: if you want to do somthing to the ui you should use handler instead of thread

Comment: I dont understand this is so easy in csharp  İf you want make game with keyboard on desktop e.keyCode==e.UP something like that ıdont remember now But in Android Studio this is so complicated I so confused I  will try your suggestion but İs there any link about this leave here thanks for helping me bro

Comment: Yes handler I know to use handler